# Does Spark allow to use Amazon Assumed Role and STS temporary credentials for Glue cross account access on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, aws-sdk, amazon-emr, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We are trying to connect to the cross-account AWS Glue catalog with the EMR spark job.
I did a study that AWS supports cross-account access for the Glue catalog in two ways.

1. **IAM** role-based.  (This is not working for me)
2. **Resource-based** policy. (This worked for me)

> So the problem scenario is, Account **A** creates **EMR** with its
> role **role_Account_A**. And role **role_Account_A** wants to access
> the **glue catalog of Account B**.
>
> - Account A creates EMR cluster with role **role_Account_A**
> - Account B has role **role_Account_B** which has access to glue and s3     with **role_Account_A** in trusted entities.
> - **role_Account_A** has sts:AssumeRole policy for resource     **role_Account_B**
> - using sdk we are able to assume role **role_Account_B** from     **role_Account_A** and getting temporary credentials.
> - EMR has configurations[{"classification":"spark-hive-site","properties":{"hive.metastore.glue.catalogid":"Account_B",  "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"}}]

```
    SparkSession sparkSession=SparkSession.builder().appName("testing glue")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider");
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", assumedcreds.getAccessKeyId());
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", assumedcreds.getSecretAccessKey());
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.session.token", assumedcreds.getSessionToken());
sparkSession.sparkContext().conf().set("fs.s3a.access.key",  assumedcreds.getAccessKeyId());
sparkSession.sparkContext().conf().set("fs.s3a.secret.key",  assumedcreds.getSecretAccessKey());
sparkSession.sparkContext().conf().set("fs.s3a.session.token", assumedcreds.getSessionToken());
sparkSession.sql("show databases").show(10, false);
```

**The error that we are getting is**

```
    Caused by: MetaException(message:User: arn:aws:sts::Account_A:assumed-role/role_Account_A/i-xxxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: glue:GetDatabase on resource: arn:aws:glue:XX-XXXX-X:Account_B:catalog 
because no resource-based policy allows the glue:GetDatabase action (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: X93Xbc64-0153-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXX))
```

> **Questions:-**
>
> - Does spark supports glue-based authentication properties for example    aws.glue.access.key?
> - As per error spark is not using assumed role    role_Account_B. It uses role_Account_A with which EMR was created.    Can we make it use
>   assumed role role_Account_B?

I will update the question details if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having an EMR instance profile role in Account A. If so, you would have to follow these and cross-account access should work

In Account B,

1. Under Glue, go to settings and add the ( EMR instance profile role A ) as principal and provide access to Account B's glue and S3. It is recommended to provide only for the buckets you need to access
2. Go to the bucket policy of the bucket that the glue table will be using and add the ( EMR instance profile role A ) as principal and provide read/write access.

Now if you run the EMR job in account A, you'll see the job running with cross-account access

It works for our purpose. Try it out

Comment: It is resource based policy that you mentioned and I have already mentioned that I was able to do it. My question was about IAM role based access.

Comment: I would be very interested in understanding cross-account RBAC too, I seem to struggle with my spark session.